# How to enable Messenger notifications on Mac 12.2.1?

Tags: notifications, monterey, facebook

I recently upgraded to MacOS 12.2.1 on an MacBook Air and now there seems to be a problem with messenger notifications.

In the messenger app it says: "messenger notifications are turned off", but when open the System Preferences, they are activated. See screenshot:

[image]

Now what is the status? Are notifications enabled or not? Is that a bug in messenger or in MacOS? The messenger app seems to be up-to-date. How to solve this problem?

Comment: since this message persists across app restarts, it's likely stored in a file in ~/Library. find the relevant settings file and delete it ? since your chats are on a server, they should be safe.

Comment: I removed the folder `Library/Application  Support/Messenger`, restarted this app, but nothing did change

Comment: What happens if you check off all the notifications options (lock screen, notif center, when mirroring)? My theory is that messenger is checking for more notification permissions than you currently provide, to be considered “on”. Also have you tested to see if the notifications work or not?

Comment: Changing notification sounds is a separate question IMO - 1 at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably a bug in the Messenger App.
This happens, when the implementation of an macOS App is not updating this part of code:

```swift
notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { success, error in {

        // Checking System Settings and apply update here

    }
}
```

Most probably, the App does not check this. A fresh reinstall (of the app) with flushing caches could fix the issue.

The right part of your screenshot shows, what the app is `allowed` to do by the system.

The left part shows the implementation and what the app `will` do when notifications occur.

Comment: How do I reinstall something with "flushing caches"? I am not a Mac expert ...

Comment: Can only answer this from a developer perspective and it also depends, what kind of data sources the app is using;
Logout of it (if a login is there), close everything, delete it from Application Library and restart (this is important as it will force osx to update some system files)
Reinstall and, The Popup asking for notification permissions shall appear when starting the app again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try turning it off and back on?

Other thing I can think of is uninstalling it with an uninstalled (ex. [App Cleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)) to make sure there are no preference files still on your Mac. Then reinstall the app.